# Drools decision table - rules not matching

Tags: spring-boot, drools

I have a hello-world type spring/drools setup. The issue is no rules fire when in theory they should.

**Decision Table:**

[image]

**Console output - server startup:**

```
package com.example.drools;
//generated from Decision Table
import com.example.drools.TestRules;
// rule values at B9, header at B4
rule "_9"
    when
        $test:TestRules(number1 == 10)
    then
        $test.add("10");
end
```

**Drools Config:**

```
@Configuration
public class DroolsConfiguration
{
  private final static String VALIDATION_RULES = "validation-rules.xls";
                                                   

  @Bean
  public KieContainer validationRulesKieContainer() {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    Resource rules = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(VALIDATION_RULES);
    
    compileXlsToDrl(rules);
    
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(rules);
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    KieBuilder builder = kieBuilder.buildAll();
    
    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
    return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());        
  }

  private static void compileXlsToDrl(Resource resource) {
    try {
        InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
        SpreadsheetCompiler compiler = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
        String drl = compiler.compile(is, InputType.XLS);
        System.out.println(drl);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class ValidationRulesEngine
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validationRulesKieContainer")
    private KieContainer validationKieContainer;
    
    public void validate() {
        KieSession kieSession = validationKieContainer.newKieSession();
        
        kieSession.addEventListener(new DebugAgendaEventListener());
        kieSession.addEventListener(new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener());
        
        TestRules tr = new TestRules(10, 20, 30);
        
        kieSession.insert(tr);
        int noOfRulesFired = kieSession.fireAllRules();
        
        System.out.println("noOfRulesFired: " + noOfRulesFired);
        System.out.println(tr);
        System.out.println(tr.getRule());                
    }
}
```

**TestRule - Fact:**

```
public class TestRules
{    
    public int number1;
    public int number2;
    public int number3;
    public List<String> rules = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public TestRules() {}
    
    public TestRules(int number1, int number2, int number3)
    {
        super();
        this.number1 = number1;
        this.number2 = number2;
        this.number3 = number3;
    }

    public void add(String rule) {  
        rules.add(rule);
    }
    
    public String getRule() {
        return this.rules.size() > 0 ? this.rules.get(0) : "";
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "TestRules [number1=" + number1 + ", number2=" + number2 + ", number3=" + number3 + ", rules=" + 
                rules.stream().map(s -> s.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]";
    }          
}
```

**Console output - result:**

```
2021-07-20 17:02:27.549 ERROR 20212 --- [nio-9016-exec-1] c.g.i.e.p.c.OfficeController             : --> Rules Engine
==>[ObjectInsertedEventImpl: getFactHandle()=[fact 0:1:1539328290:1539328290:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.example.drools.TestRules:TestRules [number1=10, number2=20, number3=30, rules=]], getObject()=TestRules [number1=10, number2=20, number3=30, rules=], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0], getPropagationContext()=PhreakPropagationContext [entryPoint=EntryPoint::DEFAULT, factHandle=[fact 0:1:1539328290:1539328290:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.example.drools.TestRules:TestRules [number1=10, number2=20, number3=30, rules=]], leftTuple=null, originOffset=-1, propagationNumber=2, rule=null, type=INSERTION]]
noOfRulesFired: 0
TestRules [number1=10, number2=20, number3=30, rules=]

2021-07-20 17:02:28.454 ERROR 20212 --- [nio-9016-exec-1] c.g.i.e.p.c.OfficeController             : <-- Rules Engine
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Changing your question to completely invalidate existing answers is considered poor form and technically and invalid edit, especially when you have multiple issues compounding each other. :-/

Comment: You see even after applying your change, the exact same issue remains. So, I tried to simplify as much as I can.

Comment: tested your rule table with the model. works for me, rule '_9' was activated, item added to the list

Comment: @Mike, is it possible for you to please share relevant dependencies in pom.xml? I suspect missing a needed dependency.

Comment: I wrote a test to check your rules code, I didn't start spring boot app. But I would advise you to try to load the table in different way, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498728/448078) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no good:

```
$test:TestRules($test.number1 == 10, $test.number2 == 20)
```

You can't refer to `$test` before you declare it. The correct syntax is:

```
$test: TestRules( number1 == 10, number2 == 20 )
```

Fix your decision table from `$test.number1 == $param` to instead be `number1 == $param`. (And do the same for `number2` adjacent.)

The rest looks fine, though I would suggest using a try-with-resources instead of a try-catch in your XLSX parsing method.

Comment: I tried that, same result. No rules fired.